# Cosmos DB Azure Table API oData Authentication REST / C#?

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to access Azure Cosmos DB using Table API.

The challenge is, despite creating SharedKeyLite, server is still returning Unauthorized - seems like SharedKeyLite is not supported or I'm generating the signature or headers wrong.

Here is the code

```
    static readonly string storageAccountName = "accountName";
    static readonly string storageAccountKey = "xxxx";
    static readonly string uri = "https://accountName.table.cosmosdb.azure.com/Contacts()";
    static readonly string utc_date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(GetResult().Result);

    }


    static async Task<string> GetResult()
    {
        // Set this to whatever payload you desire. Ours is null because 
        //   we're not passing anything in.
        Byte[] requestPayload = null;

        var requestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var requestUri = new Uri(uri);

        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //Instantiate the request message with a null payload.
        using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
        { Content = (requestPayload == null) ? null : new ByteArrayContent(requestPayload) })
        {

            ConstructHeaders(httpRequestMessage.Headers, requestDateString);

            string authorizationHeader = GenerateSharedKeyLite(storageAccountKey, storageAccountName, uri,requestDateString);
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedKeyLite", authorizationHeader);
            // Send the request.
            using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
            {
                string json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return json;
            }
        }
    }
```

These are the headers I"m adding, expansion of ConstructHeaders method. 
Refer [this link for request parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-table)

```
     //Construct the headers
    static void ConstructHeaders(HttpRequestHeaders headers, string now)
    {

        headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
        headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");
        // If you need any additional headers, add them here before creating
        //   the authorization header. 
        headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        if (headers.Contains("DataServiceVersion"))
            headers.Remove("DataServiceVersion");
        headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");
        if (headers.Contains("MaxDataServiceVersion"))
            headers.Remove("MaxDataServiceVersion");
        headers.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");
    }
```

And this is the method that creates the SharedKeyLite

```
    //Created Shared Key Lite 
    static string GenerateSharedKeyLite(string accessKey, string account, string url, string date)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);

        var canonicalizedResourceString = uri.PathAndQuery;
        var queryStart = canonicalizedResourceString.IndexOf('?');
        if (queryStart > -1)
        {
            if (queryStart < canonicalizedResourceString.Length - 1)
            {
                var path = canonicalizedResourceString.Substring(0, queryStart);
                var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(canonicalizedResourceString.Substring(queryStart + 1));
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var keyOri in parameters.Keys)
                {
                    var value = parameters[keyOri];
                    var key = keyOri.ToLowerInvariant();
                    sb.Append("\n");
                    sb.Append(key);
                    sb.Append(":");
                    sb.Append(value);
                }
                canonicalizedResourceString = canonicalizedResourceString + sb.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                canonicalizedResourceString = canonicalizedResourceString.Substring(0, canonicalizedResourceString.Length - 1);
            }
        }
        canonicalizedResourceString = $"/{account}{canonicalizedResourceString}";

        var stringToSign = $"{date}\n{canonicalizedResourceString}";
        var signedSignature = string.Empty;
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accessKey)))
        {
            var outputBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign));
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
            return $"{account}:{signature}";
        }


    }
```

Any Help? Ideally I want to perform the odata query using simple.odata, but first trying to make this work using HttpClient

Comment: Why don't you use Azure Storage Client Library directly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table?view=azure-dotnet Do you have any particular reason to write REST API accessing code by your own?

Comment: Yes, we've few generic client frameworks that consumes oData feeds.

Comment: If you still have confusions, just ask. Or you can accept my solution as an answer if it did help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy your code and it works on my side. If you haven't modified your code, please make sure your `storageAccountName` and `storageAccountKey` are correct.

BTW, in method `GenerateSharedKeyLite` there's no need to add query parameters to `canonicalizedResourceString` for entity operation. You only need to add `comp` if you want to operate component info for table or service. See [constructing-the-canonicalized-resource-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-canonicalized-resource-string).

> The query string should include the question mark and the `comp` parameter (for example, `?comp=metadata`). No other parameters should be included on the query string.